# Working in Angular, should I transform every JSON file I receive into a TypeScript model/interface/constant?

Tags: angular, typescript, mongodb, api, mqtt

My part in a home automation project is the frontend one. So far, I've managed to display data from JSON file that I created by hand based on fractions of data coming from the backend Java + MongoDB server.

But having been reading for the last 2 days about MQTT broker, I've come to the conclusion that I might need to link my application's front to the MQTT instead of the Java backend.

I am panicked, since, I can mostly display data and fiddle around with HTML, CSS, components, properties.

But have no idea whatsoever of how to interpret a JSON file apart from displaying its data. I need to do GET, POST, PUT, DELETE requests on the MQTT broker (some sort of server that intermediates between the backend server, the embedded components, and the application's frontend - my part).

How should I analyze this problem? How to break it down and actually solve it within a week? I like Angular so far, but HTTP requests seem to be out of question for my case.

Thank you all! And sorry if my question is dumb or vague, I am very new to all of this - but I'm so excited!

Comment: There are a range of ways you could do this; connecting directly to the MQTT broker from the browser (MQTT over WebSockets) being one. However as you already have the data flowing into a database (and have a Java based server) a simpler solution might be for your webclient to poll (e.g. run a GET every 30 seconds) or, if you need data once/rapidly, look into long polling, or Websockets, or [SSE](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp). We can't really give an indication as to what is best without a lot more info (but such a question is likely to be subjective).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data, if it makes sense to come from server, then it should be fine. If the data has less overhead coming from MQTT then it should be preferred.

I imagine you would do the same thing as you would for any server, find how to query or mutate data. Once you know how to access the data the rest is a matter of management.

You may store data that may need to be accessed many times throughout the FE, so you may prefer a Global State through a high order component. This is a common pattern for SPAs such as React, Angular, Vue, etc… look into passing state through a high order component (or whatever the front end modules are called in Angular).  Some common patterns are: Redux/Flux, Context API, Hooks.